# How do I render Glowing text effect

Tags: rendering

My querie probably demos my lack of current understanding of the basics, I'm in the early stages still of getting to grips with Blender, I have a simple animation i'm rendering.

**Issue:** Trying to render text emitting a glow. In nodes, i added a viewer and emission/glare etc and it shows in the "viewer" -(pictured) exactly as i want but in the box below rendering when rendering f12 it shows no emission from text, not sure what has happened.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The compositor only starts to process the image once the rendering is completed or if you have auto render enabled and already render (a partial) image, once you change the node configuration. You'll have to render the image once from start to finish, to have the entire image processed by the compositor.

Comment: Once it's finished you can view the result by switching to *Composite* instead of *Render Layer* in the drop down of the image viewer.

Comment: many thanks:) I've rendered as you said fully, the bottom viewer is on compositor and still rendered with no light emission showing what is the next step, didn't quite understand. New pic above.

Comment: Ah right, you also need to connect the output of the *Glare* node to the *Composite* node.

Comment: i'm prob doing wrong but tried connecting from "image" on glare node to "image" on the composite node but it made the connection from render layers to composite connection disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compositor only starts to process the image once the rendering is completed or in case you have activate *Auto Render* once you change the node configuration.

There is a small error in your compositing nodes, in order to see the result in the image editor you have to connect the *Image* output socket of the *Glare* node to the *Composite* node.

[image]

Once this adjustment has been made, you can render the image from start to finish. The result of the compositing can be viewed in the image editor if you switch from *Render Layer* to *Composite* in the dropdown next to the slots.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks:) That worked, have rendered an image with the light emitting, i clicked composite and it swaps between layers, I need to read up on rendering to understand more.I'll learn.  Thanks again.